# Entity Framework 6 get complext return value from a stored procedure

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

My ASP.Net MVC app needs to execute a stored procedure in order to check for duplicate work orders based upon a set of parameters. The stored procedure is large and complex, so converting it to a Linq to SQL query is out of the question. Also, we do not use Entity Data Model (EDMX) files for this; we only have the domain models, view models and a data context. The stored procedure has the following signature:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[spGetDupWOs]
    -- Add the parameters for the stored procedure here
    @ProjectName VARCHAR(200) = '""',
    @City VARCHAR(100) = '',
    @State VARCHAR(100) = '',
    @ProjectNumber VARCHAR(50) = '',
    @County VARCHAR(50) = '',
    @Customer VARCHAR(400) = '',
    @QuoteRecipients VARCHAR(400) = NULL,
    @ProjectID BIGINT = NULL
    ...

    SELECT DuplicateID, ProjectNameMatchRank, ProjectNameMatch, ProjectName ...
```

I have tried to call it in my controller like:

```
IEnumerable<DuplicateProjects> duplicateCheckResults = db.Database.SqlQuery< DuplicateProjects>("spGetDupWOs", new { ProjectName = ProjectName, City = City, State = propal.State, ProjectNumber = ProjectNumber, County = County, Owner = Owner, BID_QuoteRecipients = QuoteRecipients, ProjectID = -1 });
```

And get an exception when I run this like:

> No mapping exists from object type
>   <>f__AnonymousType6`8[[System.String, mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0,
>   Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089],[System.String,
>   mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089],[System.String, mscorlib,
>   Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089],[System.String, mscorlib,
>   Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089],[System.String, mscorlib,
>   Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089],[System.String, mscorlib,
>   Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089],[System.String, mscorlib,
>   Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089],[System.Int32, mscorlib,
>   Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089]] to
>   a known managed provider native type.

What am I doing wrong?

---

UPDATE: When I change all of the passed parameters to ObjectParamter I still get the same error message.

---

UPDATE 2:

I refactored the code a bit. Here is what it looks like now:

```
            List<SqlParameter> spl = new List<SqlParameter>();

            var ProjectNameParameter = new SqlParameter("ProjectName", project.ProjectName);
            spl.Add(ProjectNameParameter);
            var CityParameter = new SqlParameter("City", project.City);
            spl.Add(CityParameter);
            var StateParameter = new SqlParameter("State", project.State);
            spl.Add(StateParameter);
            var ProposalNumberParameter = new SqlParameter("ProjectNumber", project.ProjectNumber);
            spl.Add(ProposalNumberParameter);
            var CountyParameter = new SqlParameter("County", project.County);
            spl.Add(CountyParameter);
            var OwnerParameter = new SqlParameter("Owner", project.Owner);
            spl.Add(OwnerParameter);
            var BidRecipientParameter = QuoteRecipients != null ?
                new SqlParameter("QuoteRecipients", QuoteRecipients) :
                new SqlParameter("QuoteRecipients", "");
            spl.Add(BidRecipientParameter);
            var ProjectIDParameter = new SqlParameter("ProjectID", typeof(long));
            spl.Add(ProposalIDParameter);

            IEnumerable<DuplicateProposals> duplicateCheckResults = db.Database.SqlQuery<DuplicateProposals>("spGetDupWOs ProjectName = {0} City = {1}, State = {2}, ProjectNumber = {3}, County = {4}, Owner = {5}, QuoteRecipients = {6}, ProjectID = {7}",
                spl.ToArray());
```

Now I get the error:

The SqlParameter is already contained by another SqlParameterCollection.

Comment: Have you tried this way? `IEnumerable<DuplicateProjects> duplicateCheckResults = db.Database.SqlQuery< DuplicateProjects>("spGetDupWOs", new DuplicateProjects() { ProjectName = ProjectName, City = City, State = propal.State, ProjectNumber = ProjectNumber, County = County, Owner = Owner, BID_QuoteRecipients = QuoteRecipients, ProjectID = -1 });`  Note the `new DuplicateProjects()` instead of the anonymous type.

Comment: I'll give that a try.

Comment: The only fly in the ointment is that DuplicateProjects is the model for the output, not the input. I'm a little slow right now. Do you think I should make the input variables into SQL parameters?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Further arguments to `SqlQuery<T>` after the query string constitute a [params](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w5zay9db.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) array, which the method will use to backfill the query string with numbered parameter arguments, much as `String.Format` does. Since you're passing an anonymous object, the method is trying to treat that as one single parameter and can't convert it into a string. So, yes, you either need to use `SqlParameter` to manually add the params or alter your call to handle it in a way compatible with this method:

```
db.Database.SqlQuery< DuplicateProjects>(
    "spGetDupWOs @ProjectName = {0}, @City = {1}, @State = {2}, @ProjectNumber = {3}, @Country = {4}, @Owner = {5}, @BID_QuoteRecipients = {6}, @ProjectID = {7}",
    ProjectName,
    City,
    propal.State,
    ProjectNumber,
    County,
    Owner,
    QuoteRecipients,
    -1
);
```

*Liberal spacing added for better readability*

Comment: Chris, I refactored the code some. You can see it above, under UPDATE 2. I'm getting closer.

Comment: That fixed the code. I was getting an issue with a string array, but that was because I kept grabbing the wrong variable name.