# Entity Framework - extremely long execution time for stored procedure

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework, stored-procedures

I'm following up on my question yesterday, [Entity Framework 6 get complext return value from a stored procedure](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42677453/entity-framework-6-get-complext-return-value-from-a-stored-procedure). My stored procedure now runs under entity framework. However, it times out after 3 minutes, the connection time out.

I run the stored procedure in my SQL Server Management Studio with the line (customer information omitted):

```
EXEC spGetDupWOs @ProjectName=N'...', @City=N'...', @State=N'LA', @ProposalNum=N'201703080740-001', @County=N'...', @Owner=N'...', @QuoteRecipients=N'...', @ProjectID=-1
```

It executes in less than a second. When Entity framwork executes it, it takes forever.

Using the SQL Server Profiler, I determined that Entity Framework is sending this line to the SQL server:

```
exec sp_executesql N'EXEC spGetDupWOs',N'@ProjectName nvarchar(19),@City nvarchar(6),@State nvarchar(2),@ProjectNum nvarchar(12),@County nvarchar(10),@Owner nvarchar(23),@QuoteRecipients nvarchar(23),@ProjectID bigint',@ProjectName=N'...',@City=N'Holden',@State=N'LA',@ProposalNum=N'201703080740-001',@County=N'Livingston',@Owner=N'...',@BID_RECIP=N'...',@ProjectID=-1
```

When I run this in SSMS, it takes forever to run.

Reading the similar questions it looks like the issue is Parameter Sniffing and a change in execution plan.

Here is my call to execute the stored procedure in my application:

```
            List<DuplicateProposals> duplicateCheckResults = 
                db.Database.SqlQuery<DuplicateProposals>("spGetDupWOs", 
                spl.ToArray())
                .ToList();
```

After reading a bunch of articles online, I'm even more confused. How can I change my call to resolve this?

Comment: Have you tried fixing the parameter sniffing scenario?

Comment: That's just it. I'm so confused by what I read, I'm not sure how. Do I need to change my stored procedure or my application call?

Comment: Change the SP. For example: `CREATE PROC Thing(@param1 INT) AS DECLARE @internal_param1 INT = @param1; SELECT * FROM Table WHERE Column = @internal_param1`

Comment: @DavidG: while that works around parameter sniffing, it's an unintuitive approach compared to `OPTION (OPTIMIZE FOR ...)` or `OPTION (RECOMPILE)` on individual troublesome statements. Copying parameters locally shouldn't be necessary.

Comment: @JeroenMostert I wouldn't recommend either of those as a solution to parameter sniffing.

Comment: You can debug the call by `db.Database.Log = (s) => System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(s);` before the call.  It will tell you how long the call to server took.

Comment: It executed 180 seconds exactly before timing out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up having to convert the entire call into a single string that I passed to the SqlQuery function.

```
            string sql = string.Format("exec spGetDupWOs @ProjectName=N'{0}',@City=N'{1}',@State=N'{2}',@ProjectNumber=N'{3}',@County=N'{4}',@Owner=N'{5}',@QuoteRecipients=N'{6}',@ProjectID={7}", 
                project.ProjectName, 
                project.City,
                project.State,
                project.ProjectNumber,
                project.County,
                project.Owner,
                quoteRecipientsList, 
                "null");
```

Yes, I had to include the N prefix to the strings to make it work, I'm not sure why but it worked.

Thanks for all of the help everyone. I could not have solved this without your help.

Answer (score 2):

The issue identified is parameter sniffing in SQL Server.  There are multiple approaches to handle this, but the most optimal for your scenario depends on your real use case, utilization, etc.

Here are some options.

1. Recompile the stored procedure with every execution. This may become very heavy CPU utilization, and is typically overkill. I would NOT recommend this option unless you have a very good reason. To implement: Use
   **WITH RECOMPILE** or the **OPTION(RECOMPILE)** hint at the end of your query.
2. Optimize for hint.  This can be a workaround for the parameter sniffing, but may result in a subpar execution plan for all of your queries. Typically, not an optimal approach.  To implement: Use **OPTION(OPTIMIZE FOR UNKNOWN)**
3. Copy parameter to a local variable.  Was more common in older versions of SQL Server.  To implement: Declare a local variable, then copy the value from your input parameter to your local variable. **DECLARE @local_var1 char(1) = @InputParam1;**
4. Turn off parameter sniffing at query level. This approach uses the **QUERYTRACEON** hint. This may be the most optimal approach for this case scenario. I would recommend to explore this option as a primary strategy.  To implement: add **OPTION(QUERYTRACEON 4136)** to the end of your query.

Example:

```
SELECT * FROM  dbo.MyTable T
WHERE T.Col1 = @Param1 and T.Col2 = @Param2
OPTION(QUERYTRACEON 4136)
```

Comment: I implemented number 3 and it almost worked. I was able to determine that the stored procedure was not getting the parameters fed to it by adding some debug information in the SP. I ended up converting the entire call to a string and passing that to the SqlQuery function.